# Insert row in middle of DataGridView (C#)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would like to insert a new DataGridViewRow into my DataGridView at a specific index. If I just create a new Row like

```
DataGridViewRow dgwr = new DataGridViewRow();
datagridview1.Rows.Insert(index, dgwr);
```

I will not get the "settings" of the DataGridView, like for example my "Cells" will be 0. This does not happen if I use.

```
DataGridView1.Add();
```

But then again, then I cant chose where in the list I would like my post...

Is there anyway to combine these advantages?

/Nick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
grid.Rows.Insert(index, 1);
var addedRow = grid.Rows[index];
```

This inserts 1 empty templated row at 'index', and then simply accesses row in 'index'.
The 2nd line is for accessing the just-now-added row.

Can also shorten if you know your wished row values with:

```
grid.Rows.Insert(index, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, Etc);
```

Just have to make sure it is synced with the columns order in the grid, and it makes the row automatically with these fields.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx

Comment: Thank you! But still, I dont know what values yet, so I would just like Rows[i].Cells to be like on the other Rows (the same "Count" as DataGridView1.ColumnCount). How can I do this when Im working with the cell? :)

Comment: @Nick3 You use it as any other row in the grid. What do you mean working with the cell?

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridView` and `DataGridRowView` are just visual representations of your data source and one row in your data source. A new visual row should be displayed in your DataView after a new row is added to your data source.

If you want to get the view row when new row is added handle [RowsAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded.aspx) event.

Comment: I do not have a datasourse I just add text on the rows manually. But Thanks!